# Undefined is not a function when calling node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I've separate some logic to different file in my project,
the problem is that I got the following error

```
Cannot read property 'readFile' of undefined
```

this is the structure of my project

```
projName
   utils
     file.js
```

the file.js code is

```
module.exports = function () {
   var  fs = require('fs');
    function readFile(filePath) {
        fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log("error to read file:  " + filePath + " " + err);
            }
            return data;
        });
    }
};
```

I want to call to this module at

```
projname
    controller
         request
```

I do it with the following code
**And here I got the error**

```
   module.exports = function (app) {
        app.get('/test', function(req, res) {

            var file = require('../utils/file')();
            var fileContent = file.readFile("C://test.txt");
```

any idea what am I doing wrong here?
This is not related to async call

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @Scimonster- this is not related to async ....if you think so please explain since I already read this in the past...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file.js could be like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports.readFile = function (filePath, cb) {
  fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', cb);
};
```

and your request.js file like this:

```
var file = require('../utils/file');

module.exports = function (app) {

  var fileContent = '';
  var filePath = 'C://test.txt';

  file.readFile(filePath, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log("error to read file:  " + filePath + " " + err);
    }

    console.log(data);
    fileContent = data;
  }); 

  // some content

}
```

**Regarding the async call**
when you call a method from Node.JS libaries, it is usually a async call, that means that the result of the function is not going to return immediately:

```
var data = fs.readFile(filePath);
```

instead it is going to return at some time later, so the only way you can get the results later is passing by a function that is going to be called when the results are ready:

```
fd.readFile(filePath, function dataReady (err, data) {
  console.log(data)
});
```

**Regarding module.exports** when you export some logic of a file that you created in Node.JS, you can return your function on the following ways:

```
// exporting a function, myModule.js
module.exports = function () { 
  console.log('hello');
};

// consuming myModule.js
var someFunction = require('./myModule.js');
someFunction(); // prints 'hello';
```

---

```
// exporting a function, myModule.js
module.exports.readFile = function () {
  console.log('hello');
};

// consuming myModule.js
var myModule = require('./myModule.js');
myModule.readFile(); // prints 'hello';
```

**UPDATE**:
In your file.js you are exporting a function that is going to receive a file path and a function called callback as the second parameter (yes, you read it well, a function as a parameter) which is going to be called once the fs.readFile get the file content.

```
module.exports.readFile = function (filePath, callback) {
  fs.readFile(filePath, 'ut8', function (err, fileContent) {
    callback(err, fileContent);
  });
}
```

then in your request.js file, you are using your module (file.js) you just created, and the function that your module is exporting accepts a string as parameter called filePath, and a function as parameter called callback: `file.readFile(filePath, callback)`

so when your module file.js get the content file is going to call to your callback function parameter.

```
var file = require('../utils/file');

file.readFile(filePath, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log("error to read file:  " + filePath + " " + err);
  }

  console.log(data);
  fileContent = data;
});
```

I hope that this helps to clarify a little bit your knowledge about callbacks.

Comment: Thanks,Im little bit confused regard the callback,can you please provide example how should I use it in my case?

Answer (score 1):

You don't return anything in your `module.exports` function. In fact, you don't even need to set `module.exports` to a function. Just simply export your function:

```
var  fs = require('fs');
function readFile(filePath) {
    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log("error to read file:  " + filePath + " " + err);
        }
        return data;
    });
}
exports.readFile = readFile;
```

---

Also, your `return data` isn't going to work, as `fs.readFile` is asynchronous. You need to use callbacks. So, your `readFile` function might look more like:

```
function readFile(filePath, callback) {
    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log("error to read file:  " + filePath + " " + err);
        }
        callback(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks voted up!, Can you please show me what to you mean by using callback and if for example I've more then one function to exports how should I do that (e.g. also write file,deleteFile etc) ?

Comment: Edited to explain a bit about the callback. And for other functions just do `function writeFile(){} exports.writeFile = writeFile;` the same way.

Comment: Thanks,I try what you write and I got error undefined is not a function
in callback(data); any idea?

Comment: You also need to pass a callback function when you call `file.readFile`, like you do in `fs.readFile`. You might want to review [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/3187556).

Comment: Thanks but I not sure in my case what shuould I put in the callback...can you provide example....